# Window Fails to Open ElectronNET/Electron.NET Application

Tags: npm, electron

I am trying to start the [ElectronNET-API-Demo application]from ElectronNET's official github repo.
(https://github.com/ElectronNET/electron.net-api-demos][1](https://github.com/ElectronNET/electron.net-api-demos))

The majority of the time, `electronize start` appears to run and I get`stdout: BridgeConnector connected!` message.
There is an executable running in task manager, but the application window never appears. Also, if I do "ctr-c" in cmd, I need to manually end the "ElectronNET-API-Demo.exe" in task manager.

I ran it twice without any issue, and without changing anything on my end.
I am not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I wasn't even able to run it once, just runs in the background

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the bootstrap method in the sample. Perhaps `window.OnReadyToShow` never fires? I'm not sure at the moment, but to get up and running with the sample, simply replace the call to `ElectronBootstrap()` with `Task.Run(async () => await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync());`

So, the `startup.cs Configure` looks like:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        if (HybridSupport.IsElectronActive)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync());
        }
    }
```